# Orfeo Toolbox KMeans Classification failure

Tags: classification, landsat, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to process a Landsat8 OLI image using the Orfeo Toolbox  Unsupervised KMeans Classification application.

I obtain the following error message:

```
Error when loading model 20140915_E1B1234_km.tif_model.txt
```

It works fine on Sentinel2 MSI images.

Any idea what could cause the application to fail on my Landsat image, although it works on the Sentinel image? Has anybody already encountered this issue?

Comment: I found a solution. I had NaN pixels in my image. After replacing them with no data values (using the ManageNoData application) the KMeans classification worked fine. 
So my conclusion is that the NaN pixels were causing the issue.

Comment: it would be nice to add this as an answer, because comments are not well visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an open issue](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/otb/issues/1586) about that on OTB's bug tracker, currently under investigation.

Comment: Yes I opened it actually, thanks for letting me know here.

Answer (score 1):

OTB's KMeansClassification app failed because my image contained nan pixels (here is the [open issue](https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/otb/issues/1586) on OTB's bug tracker).
Converting nans to nodata using OTB's ManageNoData app should bypass the issue.